# split a drawn path into pieces using different paths

Tags: java, android, canvas, path

I'm making a drawing app on Android. Is it possible to split a drawn path into pieces using different paths (Paint's Xfermode is PorterDuff.Mode.DST_OUT or PorterDuff.Mode.Clear)? Like XODO or S-Note (Galaxy), because I want to split the path and then use the Block eraser (erase the whole path at once) to erase only one separate path.

Is there a good way to do it differently?

I tried using the CCW algorithm to use intersections at the points of the paths, and I tried using an algorithm that checks if the area overlaps considering the thickness of the pen, but when I draw the drawn path, the points are not consistent depending on the speed of the pen, so it does not separate accurately.

I wanted to try using PathMeasure and intersection, but I gave up because it doesn't seem to be a good way to use the points of the Path.